# Запуск пользовательского ящика lxc с учётом Apparmor

Tags: linux, debian, lxc

При запуске пользовательского ящика в lxc ругается на apparmor.

```
$ lxc-start -n foobar -F
lxc-start: foobar: lsm/apparmor.c: apparmor_prepare: 974 Cannot use generated
profile: apparmor_parser not available
                                                                                                                  lxc-start:
foobar: start.c: lxc_init: 
899 Failed to initialize LSM
                            lxc-start: foobar: start.c: __lxc_start: 1917 Failed
to initialize container "foobar"
lxc-start: foobar: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start
lxc-start: foobar: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be
obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
```

Как это исправить?

## Дополнение

Lxc ящик с отключенным упоминание apparmor в файле настроек ящика запускается как и положено, но необходимо запускать его с учётом этих настроек.

## Данные

- ОС: Debian 10 64bit
- Lxc: 3.0.3

Файл настроек:

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/lxc/foobar/config 

lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/userns.conf
lxc.arch = linux64

lxc.apparmor.profile = generated
lxc.apparmor.allow_nesting = 1
lxc.idmap = u 0 165536 65536
lxc.idmap = g 0 165536 65536
lxc.rootfs.path = dir:/home/barfoo/.local/share/lxc/foobar/rootfs
lxc.uts.name = foobar

lxc.net.0.type = empty
```

Comment: *apparmor_parser not available* — надо поставить apparmor. ну либо уберите упоминания о нём из конфигурация контейнера. хотя не уверен, что второе поможет: apparmor не зря присутствует среди рекомендуемых в пакете lxc.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да, спасибо, без него это работает, но нужно с ним. Сам apparmor установлен был.